# Use YAML variables to name keys

Tags: ruby, yaml, symfony, foselasticabundle

I need to use a YAML variable to name a YAML key. 
I've tried this, but yaml validator complains that its not valid YAML

```
#Elastic search configuration
variable_key: &variable_key_name vodacom_salimdev_local
fos_elastica:
   clients:
       default:
           host: %fos_elastica_host%
           port: %fos_elastica_port%
           logger: false
           headers: { Authorization: some_security_token }
   indexes:
       *variable_key_name:
           client: default
           settings:
                index:
                 analysis:
                   analyzer:
                     custom_analyzer :
                       type     :    custom
```

The reason i want a variable name for a key is because, i'll be reading the key from a different file. How do i name my index names using variables ?

Comment: Do you control the loading and parsing of the file?

Comment: @Anthony No control is done, am simply reading the file.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Have you checked the yaml spec?  http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html I don't see anything that indicates that node anchors can be used that way you are showing.  Which yaml validator are you using?

Comment: Can you copy / past your external file ?

Comment: I am voting to reopen because while the error description could be better, it is pretty clear that the question is why the given code is not valid YAML. Also, the existing answer does not answer this question.

Comment: @Cerad There is nothing which forbids it, but it hits an ugly detail in the spec which I would explain if this question wasn't closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
#Elastic search configuration
variable_key: &variable_key_name vodacom_salimdev_local
fos_elastica:
   clients:
       default:
           host: %fos_elastica_host%
           port: %fos_elastica_port%
           logger: false
           headers: { Authorization: some_security_token }
   indexes:
       %index1%:
           client: default
           settings:
                index:
                 analysis:
                   analyzer:
                     custom_analyzer :
                       type     :    custom
```

Where the `index1` var is defined in your `parameters.yml` or `config.yml` files. (or any parameters section of your loaded YAML files)

```
parameters:
    index1: my_main_app_es_index_name
```

Comment: That's defined in a different file that i haven't included here. Lets focus on how i can use variables for key naming @coil

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: @electronicsalim your response is cryptic explain your problem , otherwise this solution seems correct.

Comment: @COil Your solution works, the %index1% nailed it.. hahaha Thanks man.

Comment: You're welcome @electronicsalim , can you accept the answer please? :)

Comment: why not! :) ...

Comment: Thanks. Your question doesn't deserve the -4. The part about an external perhaps was unclear, you could modify your question to be more clear.